# How can I write a formatted STL file using Java?

Tags: java, file-format

I understand an STL file is formatted as:

```
solid (HELIX)

facet normal ni nj nk 

outer loop

          vertex v1x v1y v1
          vertex v2x v2y v2z
          vertex v3x v3y v3z
    endloop
endfacet

endsolid (HELIX)
```

But I have **no** idea how to tell Java to save a file as this!

I understand I have to use a `FileWriter`.

Any chance of some help?

Comment: I suggest that you read the Java Tutorial on Basic I/O - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html.  That will give you lots of ideas on how to save a file in Java.

Comment: appreciated. still doesn't help me code for an STL format. I have successfully written code to save a file as csv, dxf etc. but can not get a working code for stl

Comment: Show us your (non-working) code.  The file format is very simple, and I'm having difficulty understanding why you cannot write it yourself.  (Or if you are being lazy, why you cannot find an example to "borrow" using Google.)